# How do I guide my users to input their silence threshold and vocal range

Tags: games, sound

My game needs to know when users sing a high note, a low note and when they are silent.

I tried using sliders (with energy level or pitch as background).
I can use those to config the threshold and range precisely.
But nobody seems to understand that.

Then I tried to make them keep silent, make noise, sing a high and a low note while long pressing the screen by displaying text caption.
But people still misuse the config screens all the time.

Anyone have any good idea about this?

Comment: One thing you could try is to play a high note when the screen displays the text caption, then tell them to try and imitate the sound.

Comment: Could you potentially show us some designs you've worked on? That could help us help you.

Comment: ok, i will upload a video tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

I think the "noise and silent" configuration part is on you as it's very hard for the user to understand what it means to at one point be silent (which is the easy part) and in the other make noise - what kind of noise is he supposed to make? So your game should be able to filter out the back noises and hopefully just get the singing of the user.
Now the user only needs to configure two things - His high and low notes which are pretty understandable and can be configured in a fun way. Maybe ask the user 'how high/low can you go' and then rate him (or just congratulate him either way) on his performance.

Anyway, I don't really know what your game is about and who is the intended user base but I think that config can be simple and fun enough...

Comment: A mini game as config seems a good idea, I will try implementing it and test my users' feedback. I'm thinking of making my users sing a scale.